# How to get this additional data with Existing Query

Tags: mysql

Presently, i am using this query to get some information which i need and is correct

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.AS_No SOURCE, b.AS_No TARGET
FROM
    as_path a,
    as_path b
WHERE
    a.Update_ID = b.Update_ID
        AND a.Path_Index = b.Path_Index - 1 
        AND a.Update_ID IN (
            SELECT  Update_ID 
            FROM (
                SELECT * 
                FROM bgpstorage.announce_update t1
                JOIN (
                    SELECT IP as i, MAX(Update_ID) as maxupdate 
                    FROM bgpstorage.announce_update
                    GROUP BY IP
                ) x 
                ON t1.IP = x.i 
                AND t1.Update_ID = x.maxupdate
            ) sub
        );
```

The script above gets the latest state of all as_path's in the database.

But now, i want to get all the latest in a particular time(e.g 2013-2-2 -> 2013-2-3). So how can i add a conditional statement to produce only results that exist between a particular "Time" range from the update_detail table ?

Comment: those don't look like time frames to me?

Comment: Dpm't see `bgpstorage` in your list above, nor the specific relationship between `as_path` and `update_detail`.

Comment: @SamDeHaan in the updates table, i have updates and their time. So each updateid has a time. Now i want to group that query only from a time period e.g July to August. Am i missing some explanation ?

Comment: I was referring to the values '2013-2-2011'. What are those intended to represent?

Comment: @SanuelJackson bgpstorage is the name of the database. I use it to access a table as you can see in the query. And for the relationship, can you see an Update_ID foreign key that appears in as_path ?

Comment: @SamDeHaan thats a mistake !!! Sorry

Comment: offtop, looks like a Linux, what dbDesigner you use? I'm looking for one like this for my Ubuntu, but can't found a good.

Comment: @vp_arth try MysqlWorkbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Time' you have is not formatted correct (2013-2-2011 is not valid).  However, given valid TIMESTAMP values, you can use the following:

```
SELECT
    SOURCE, TARGET FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT
    a.AS_No SOURCE, b.AS_No TARGET, c.`Time` TRANGE
FROM
    as_path a,
    as_path b,
    update_detail c
WHERE
    a.Update_ID = b.Update_ID
        AND a.Path_Index = b.Path_Index - 1 
        AND a.Update_ID IN (
            SELECT  Update_ID 
            FROM (
                SELECT * 
                FROM bgpstorage.announce_update t1
                JOIN (
                    SELECT IP as i, MAX(Update_ID) as maxupdate 
                    FROM bgpstorage.announce_update
                    GROUP BY IP
                ) x 
                ON t1.IP = x.i 
                AND t1.Update_ID = x.maxupdate
            ) sub
        )
    )
WHERE `TRANGE` BETWEEN '2013-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-02 23:59:59';
```

However, your **Time** field is type VARCHAR, so unless you actually have a Time/Date/Timestamp field, you will likely be unable to check if something is in an range.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to make it VARCHAR since sometimes the updates time from where i get the logs could be corrupt like `2013-03-1 00xdw` So if i had DATETIME, the constraint won't let these data to be inserted. Is it possible to do something like `'DATE(2013-02-01 00:00:00') AND DATE('2013-02-02 23:59:59')`  ?

Comment: Note sure, you would have to convert the field.  Then instead, handle the inserting of the data better so that value is a proper date, or null if invalid.

Comment: If you notice, it is not part of the same SQL select.  Basically, it is a wrapper around your condition, however, you can always switch it to  `) table1 HAVING table1.TRANGE BETWEEN '' AND ''`;

Comment: I would suggest using [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-premium) over MySQLWorkbench as it is superior in almost every facet. It tremendously simplifies building complex queries.